# binding this to the current function

Tags: jquery

I'm using same element in multiple functions like below:

```
$('.edit').on('click',function(){
var elem1 = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(0);
var elem2 = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(1);
console.log(elem1);
});
$('.update').on('click',function(){
var elem1 = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(0);
var elem2 = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(1);
console.log(elem1);
});
```

So, I want to sort my variable outside the function so that they can be referenced in multiple functions like below:

```
var elem1 = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(0);
var elem2 = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(1);
$('.edit').on('click',function(){
console.log(elem1);
});
$('.update').on('click',function(){
console.log(elem1);
});
```

But `$(this)` doesn't refer to the current function context. So, how should I manage?

Comment: You can't do that, it has to go inside the event handlers callback

Comment: outside the function $(this) will not be able to refer to any DOM element so if you want to use $(this) then it should be inside the function scope. Can you elaborate what you're trying to achieve, it might provide more ways to get a work around.

Comment: any idea so i can define variables just only once and refer to them in multiple functions?

Comment: Yes you can define variable once and then use them later in other functions, but in current scenerio what do you want to achieve, can you please elaborate what functionality you are expecting. :)

Comment: how about a `function` that takes object and returns what you need like, `function(obj){return $(obj).closest('tr').find('td').eq(0);}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` refers to the scope where the method/function is called. So in your example code, `this` is actually global scope (`window` in browser).

You could pass `this` as an argument.

```
var elem1 = function(ref) {
  return $(ref).closest('tr').find('td').eq(0)
};
var elem2 = function(ref) {
  return $(ref).closest('tr').find('td').eq(1);
}

$('.edit').on('click',function(){
  console.log(elem1(this));
});
$('.update').on('click',function(){
  console.log(elem1(this));
});
```